# Progress bar in Shiny waiting a SQL return

Tags: r, shiny

I have some SQL queries which can take 1-3 min to return a result so I need to implement a progress bar in Shiny to warn the operator

How the simplest way to do that ?

Thank you

Here my UI.R :

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Measures"),
sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("base", "Select DB", 

     c("base1"="base-1","base2"="base-2")),
     uiOutput("selectComp")
  ),


 mainPanel(

     plotlyOutput("plot")
       ))
```

Here my server.R

```
 Library(RODBC) 

 shinyServer(function(input,output){

 refDataFrame <- reactive({

 if(input$base == "base1")   {

 data_test <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="login")   

 Ref_comp <- sqlQuery(data_test, paste ("SQL query1"),as.is=T)
 odbcClose(data_test)

}

if(input$base == "base2")   {

 data_test <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="login")   

 Ref_comp <- sqlQuery(data_test, paste ("SQL query2"),as.is=T)
odbcClose(data_test)

}

Ref_comp
})

output$selectComp <- renderUI(
selectInput("comp","Select step", 
                 choices=refDataFrame()[["STEP_NAME"]])
          )

 })
```

Comment: Check out this article from RStudio about progress indicators: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html

Comment: You can check the `busyIndicator` in the package `shinysky`. Although its not a progress bar, it shows indicates that some process in going on and is very easy to add.